# contenteditable on the parent, but not on all children

Tags: html

I'm trying to populate two columns with some content in the following way (this is expected behavior)

```
<div id="identifier_0"></div> | <p id="paragraph_0"></p>
                              |
------------------------------| -------------------------
<div id="identifier_1"></div> | <p id="paragraph_1"></p>
                              |
                              |
                              |
----------------------------- | -------------------------
<div id="identifier_2"></div> | <p id="paragraph_2"></p>
----------------------------- | -------------------------
```

every `paragraph_n` is provided by my Rails backend. Every `identifier_n` is autogenerated on the fly by a javascript script (because they identify the paragraph to the right, which might change because of user input)

I want the paragraphs column to be `contenteditable=true` as a whole (so users can join paragraphs or split a paragraph into many, or basically edit the text inside) and identifier column to be `contenteditable=false`, so my javascript is the only one allowed to change them.

Currently it looks like this:

```
<div id="container" contenteditable="true">
  <p id="paragraph_0" class="paragraph"></p>
  <p id="paragraph_1" class="paragraph"></p>
  <div id="identifier_0" class="identifier"></div>
  <div id="identifier_1" class="identifier"></div>
</div>
```

But this makes both columns, the paragraphs and the identifiers, inherit the `contenteditable=true` attribute. And I only want the paragraphs column to have it.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Thanks in advance

---

(Answer in comments ==> just add contenteditable="false" to the identifier_n, and it will do it even if wrapped inside a contenteditable="true" div)

Comment: What have you tried doing to solve this problem?

Comment: why don't you simply put the `contenteditable="true"` on the paragraph tags directly?

Comment: Because if I put the contenteditable="true" in every paragraph the user can't join two paragraphs into one (which would trigger the javascript to regenerate the identifiers with the new number of paragraphs).

Comment: All my paragraphs must be inside a <div contenteditable="true"> so the user can split them into many paragraphs or merge two into one. Maybe there is a way to make each identifier row inherit the paragraph's row height? (Thanks for your comments)

Comment: Ok I found it.

I just needed to add the attribute ```contenteditable="false"``` to every identifier_n.

This way I can keep the div wrapping all my content with ```contenteditable="true" ``` but select what elements don't inherit this property. And my rows populate properly this way

YAY!!!

Comment: Should I remove the question or edit it with an answer? What is proper SO behaviour? Thanks!

Comment: You can keep it, but remove all CSS grid related information. This is not related to CSS grid at all.

Comment: Thanks! done! I left it as an html question, as it was a matter of html attributes!

Comment: Remove ALL grid-related information. That includes your ascii tables, the css etc. None of that has any relevance for your question.